# Flask redirect as function return not working

Tags: python, flask

I am having a problem with returning a flask redirect from a function. I am probably missing something simple but would really appreciate some help.

Here is my views.py

```
from .tasks import get_stuff
from flask import render_template 


@app.route('/get-stuff')
    def get_stuff(stuff_name):
        stuff = get_stuff(stuff_name)
        return render_template('stuff.html', stuff=stuff)
```

Here is my function which is in tasks.py

```
import os

from flask import redirect, request, url_for


def get_stuff(stuff_name):
    if os.environ.get('SOME_VARIABLE') is None:
        return redirect(url_for('some_url', next=request.url))
    stuff = "Some stuff here"
    return stuff
```

And my stuff.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h1 class="uppercase">{{ stuff }}</h1>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

So because SOME_VARIABLE is not set I want it to redirect to another page where I will get the user to set SOME_VARIABLE. But this is not happening I am getting `<Response 241 bytes [302 FOUND]>`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you're still calling `return render_template` in your handler, whatever the result of the call to the task. You need to return that result directly if it is a redirect.

Potentially you could return a flag as well from that task, to tell the calling function what to do:

```
if os.environ.get('SOME_VARIABLE') is None:
    return True, redirect(url_for('some_url', next=request.url))
stuff = "Some stuff here"
return False, stuff
```

and in the handler:

```
redirect, stuff = get_stuff(stuff_name)
if redirect:
    return stuff
return render_template('stuff.html', stuff=stuff)
```

But really this is all far too complex. You should either get the task to return the full response no matter what happens - ie render the template there, rather than in the handler - or move the whole logic into the handler function.

Comment: Daniel, thank you very much for this helpful explanation. It has helped me to understand the issue properly and to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, You have twice defined `get_stuff` function, once in `tasks.py` and second time in `views.py`.

Second thing I notice, You are rerouting to `/some_url`, while I don't see You actually defined that route.